# TypeError: persona.comparePositionTo is not a function discord.js

Tags: nodejs, npm, discord.js

Me da error en la linea 14 es un comando de ban, en esa linea detecta si el rango del baneado es mas alto por que yo antes usaba Discord.js 11 y ahora uso 12 y cambio la manera. Ya pregunte en un server de discord pero no responden, Agradezco su ayuda

```
module.exports = (client, message, args) => {
    if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
        return message.channel.send("No tengo permisos");
      }
  
      if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
        return message.channel.send("Perdón, pero no tienes permisos");
      }
  
      let persona = message.mentions.members.first();
      if (!persona) {
        return message.channel.send("Debes mencionar a un **Usuario** para **Banear**.");
      } else if (
        persona.highest.comparePositionTo(message.member.highest) <= 0 > 0
      ) {
        return message.channel.send(
          "Este **Usuario** esta en la misma o mayor nivel de jerarquía que tu, ¡No puedes **Banearlo**!"
        );
      }
  
      var razon = args.slice(1).join(" ");
      if (!razon) {
        razon = `Razon no especificada`;
      }
  
      razon = razon + `, Baneado por ${message.author.tag}`;
  
      persona
        .ban(razon)
        .catch(e => message.reply("Ocurrio un **error** desconocido."));
      message.channel.send(`Listo, **Banie** a **${persona.user.tag}**`);
  }
```

Comment: nunca he visto esa función en discord js y por lógica parece imposible determinar si un rango es mayor que otro, lo que debes de verificar es que tenga los perimsos o roles necesarios